# Illegal character error when using unicode for hot pepper in Postman

Tags: html, unicode, postman, email-templates

I am using postman to upload email templates. I have a hot pepper as part of the subject line

```
"subject": "It is getting spicy is it not?
```

but when I click send I get the following error

```
Subject is not valid: Error: Illegal character '\ufffd' at position 29
```

I need the hot pepper in the subject line but not sure how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is that the subject of an email is an email header, and headers can only contain ASCII

However RFC 1342 gives a way to fix this. See [this article](https://ncona.com/2011/06/using-utf-8-characters-on-an-e-mail-subject/) for more information.